# Subquery inside Rpad

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, maxlength

I am trying to display the column `Name` from the table `GOODCUST` with a dynamic length, which is the longest value in name (which using just the maximum length is 17).   That works but the problem is the name of the Column Name1 has a really long length and I don't know why.

```
select RPAD("Name",(select max(length("Name")) from GOODCUST ))"Name1" 
from  GOODCUST
```

This is the table GOODCUST:

```
Name
------------------------------
MIKE andd SAM inc.
Black Giant
Mother Goose
BLUE SKY LTD
```

This is the result of the query:

```
Name1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Black Giant
Mother Goose
BLUE SKY LTD
MIKE and SAM inc.
```

This is how it should look:

```
Name1
-----------------

Black Giant
Mother Goose
BLUE SKY LTD
MIKE and SAM inc.
```

Comment: Your issue is not the *contents* of the column but the width of the column itself.  This is usually handled by resetting the width of the column using SQLPlus commands.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL*Plus (or similar client) to run the query.  SQL*Plus uses metadata from the data dictionary to format the display.  So the allocated space for `"Name"` will the length of the column.

However, the "`Name1"`  column is derived by the query, it's dynamic.  The client has no idea how long it's going to be so it uses a standard "very long string" length.

But it's just the layout: the actual length of the column is what we'd expect...

```
SQL> select "Name"
  2         , length("Name") lname
  3         , length(RPAD("Name",(select max(length("Name")) from GOODCUST ))) lname1
  4  from  GOODCUST
  5  /

Name                                LNAME     LNAME1
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
MIKE andd SAM inc.                     18         18
Black Giant                            11         18
Mother Goose                           12         18
BLUE SKY LTD                           12         18

SQL>
```

If the title formatting bothers you that much SQL*Plus has a command to pre-define it:

```
SQL> col "Name1" format a18
SQL> select RPAD("Name",(select max(length("Name")) from GOODCUST ))"Name1" 
  2  from  GOODCUST
  3  /

Name1
------------------
MIKE andd SAM inc.
Black Giant
Mother Goose
BLUE SKY LTD

SQL>
```

Note that if your column formatting specifies a value smaller that the max length of the column the output will be wrapped....

```
SQL> col "Name1" format a14
SQL> /

Name1
--------------
MIKE andd SAM
inc.

Black Giant


Mother Goose


BLUE SKY LTD



SQL>
```